# Google Spreadsheet SUMIFs equivalent

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I need a SUMIFs equivelent in google spreadsheet. It only has SUMIF, no IFS.

here is my data:

```
#   Salesman    Term (Month)    Amount
1   Bob         1           1,717.09
2   John        1           634.67
3   Bob         1           50.00
4   Bob         1           1,336.66
5   Bob         1           0.00
6   Bob         1           55.00
7   Bob         300         23,803.97
8   Bob         300         24,483.91
9   Bob         300         20,010.03
10  Bob         300         41,191.62
11  Bob         300         40,493.14
12  Bob         300         10,014.01
13  John        1           100.00
13  John        100         100.00
```

I want to add everything that BOB sold that the term is equal to or less then 100. I also want to SUM everything that bob sold that the term is greater then 100. Same for John.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `FILTER` function combined with the `SUM`function. In your example with Bob, your function would be like (assuming your data columns is from `A` to `C`):

```
=SUM(FILTER(C:C;A:A="Bob";B:B<=100))
```

Answer (score 0):

The new Google Spreadsheet, now has the `SUMIFS` function available.

You can use the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS(F1:F14,D1:D14, "=Bob",F1:F14, ">=100",E1:E14, "<100")
```

If you want to perform the calculation for John as well, I can recommend the following:

```
=QUERY(D1:F14, "SELECT D, SUM(F) WHERE E<100 AND F>=100 GROUP BY D LABEL D 'Who', SUM(F) 'Total'")
```

See example file I created: [SUMIFS on DATA](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheets/d/1TTrDpsywOcSbclAvcKI1TwqSus33J2716BEkXw8bwe4/edit?usp=sharing)